# the values in a dynamic allocated array can be neither accessed nor changed

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, dynamic-allocation

I wrote a program to calculate the arithmetic mean and covariance of an array of a dynamic size (given by user), which was declared using malloc, but the program didn't print the expected output. thus, I used Breakpoints to watch the values within the array, and I found out that the values don't change.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter n: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double sum = 0, m, spv;
    double *x = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%f", x[i]);
        sum += x[i];
    }
    m = sum / n;
    printf("Mittel = %f\n", m);
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        sum += pow((x[i] - m), 2);
    }
    spv = sum / (n - 1);
    printf("SPV = %f\n", spv);
    free(x);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Two problems, both leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): The first is that arguments to [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) should be *pointers*. The second is that `"%f"` is for `float`.

Comment: Use & in  scanf("%f", &x[i]);

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had written the code originally with "&" within scanf but I erased it by mistake. the problem was with the format specifier. it works well now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%f", &x[i]);` You need to pass the address.

Also check the return value of `malloc`. And don't cast the result of `malloc`.

As you are reading `double` use `%lf`. `scanf("%lf",&x[i]);`

```
double *x = malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
if( x == NULL){
   fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in malloc");
   exit(1);
}
```

As per standard (c99)(**§7.21.6.9**)

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

For not using the `&` the `scanf` will try to write in memory location denoted by `x[i]` instead of `&x[i]`. As it contains garbage value it may be some out of memory location, leading to an undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had written the code originally with "&" within scanf but I erased it by mistake. the problem was with the format specifier. it works well now.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` expects an address as argument

change this

```
scanf("%f", x[i]);
```

to

```
scanf("%f", &x[i]);
```

and yeah the "%f" -> "%lf"